# ubuntu 13.04 64 bit AR8161 usually off net

Tags: 13.04, networking, atheros

I have installed Atheros AR8161 driver from  [compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/03/04/)
and can also connect to the network but keep getting disconnected.

In order to reconnect, I have to pull out the network cable and plug it in.

what can i do ?

Answer (score 0):

13.04 was released with the working alx driver, so just get rid of the compat-drivers package

```
sudo apt-get purge compat-drivers-2013-03-04-u
```